# Update Table compare to other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table 1

| Numb | Fee | Fee1 | Fee2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 10 | 20 | 30 |

Table 2

| Numb | Fee | Fee1 | Fee2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 50 | null | null |
| 101 | null | 20 | null |
| 101 | null | null | 30 |
| 101 | null | null | null |

I want to update table 1 when compared to table 2 to all fee,fee1 & fee2 to null because
in table 2 already we have values.

I tried

```
update m set
    m.Fee = case when l.fee is not null then null else m.fee end
    , m.fee1 = case when l.fee1 is not null then null else m.fee1 end
    , m.fee2 = case when l.fee2 is not null then null else m.fee2 end
from table1 m
Join table2 l on m.Numb = l.Numb;
```

I tried above update statement but I'm getting the values in table1 but I want null.

I want output as

Table 1

| Num | Fee | Fee1 | Fee2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | null | null | null |

Comment: Maybe you think the question is clear... but it isn't. Why do you use alias m in your update sentence, if there is no any alias m in your tables?

Comment: Now its clear..

Comment: At least for me... not yet. What do you mea with "I want to update table 1 when compared to table 2 to all fee,fee1 & fee2 to null because in table 2 already we have values."

Comment: When table1 compared with table2 if we have values is table2 then we need to update table1 as null

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could do what you want

```
update m
set 
  Fee = null,
  Fee1 = null,
  Fee2 = null
from table1 m
where 1 = (
  select 
    case 
      when 
        max(isnull(l.Fee,-1)) <> -1 and
        max(isnull(l.Fee1,-1)) <> -1 and 
        max(isnull(l.Fee2,-1)) <> -1
        then 1
      else 0
    end
    from table2 l
    where l.Numb = m.Numb
    group by l.Numb
)
```

Comment: Because of `NULL`  "datatype" can be invalid for aggregation, I replaced it by -1 in the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

By joining the tables your case expression is evaluated for all rows which is not what you want; I think you need to use `exists`

```
update t1 set
    t1.fee= Iif(exists (select * from table2 t2 where t2.Numb=t1.Numb and t2.fee  is null), t1.fee,  null) 
    t1.fee1=Iif(exists (select * from table2 t2 where t2.Numb=t1.Numb and t2.fee1 is null), t1.fee1, null) 
    t1.fee2=Iif(exists (select * from table2 t2 where t2.Numb=t1.Numb and t2.fee2 is null), t1.fee2, null) 
from table1 t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this with your same approach apply where clause filter if required.

```
update m set
    m.Fee = case when l.fee is not null then null else l.fee end
    , m.fee1 = case when l.fee1 is not null then null else l.fee1 end
    , m.fee2 = case when l.fee2 is not null then null else l.fee2 end
from table1 m
Join table2 l on m.Numb = l.Numb
--    Where (l.fee is null or l.fee1 is null or l.fee2 is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest aggregating `table2` and using that for the `update`:

```
update m
    set fee = (case when l.fee is null then m.fee end),
        fee1 = (case when l.fee1 is null then m.fee1 end),
        fee2 = (case when l.fee2 is null then m.fee2 end)
from table1 m join
     (select l.numb, max(fee) as fee, max(fee1) as fee1, max(fee2) as fee2
      from table2 l
      group by l.numb
     ) l
     on m.Numb = l.Numb;
```